# Bind data from component to template

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to make a loop to print images if found.

My Code :

```
this.chatImage = this.responseData.Attatchments

for (let index = 0; index < this.chatImage.length; index++) {
    const element =  this.chatImage[index];

    if ( this.chatImage[index].FileData == "") {
        this.imgSrc = this.chatImage[index].FileData ;
    }
}
```

My template :

```
<img id="photo"[src]="imgSrc" />
```

I loop in the attachments array and check if fileData have value or not then 
change src of img to print the image but I got src Unknown

Comment: Did you mean to do `FileData != ""`?

Comment: Side note - you create the `element` const, but don't use it (you keeping doing `this.chatImage[index]`)

Comment: No I want mean if fileData have a value

Comment: It should be `!!this.chatImage[index].FileData`, what you wrote means that FileData equals empty string

Comment: Try this: `<img id="photo" [src]=imgSrc />`